# how to detect br tag in string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a demo in which i display maximum 30 characters (complete characters).It will run fine .But my problem fail when there is br tag in my given string .As we all know that br break line .so I want to break when when where i found br tag.
when i have this string :

```
var str = "Ben Nadel reviews the various approaches to Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans  substring";
```

**output** :

```
Ben Nadel reviews the various
approaches to Sachin Ramesh
Tendulkar is a former Indian
cricketer widely acknowledged
as the greatest batsman of the
modern generation, popularly
holds the title among his
fans Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar
is a former Indian cricketer
widely acknowledged as the
greatest batsman of the modern
generation, popularly holds
the title among his
fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is
a former Indian cricketer
widely acknowledged as the
greatest batsman of the modern
generation, popularly holds
the title among his fans
substring
```

that is fine.
But when I added br tag in my string my concept fail to show 30 characters.

```
  br string
var str = "Ben Nadel <br /> reviews the various approaches to Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former <br /> Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern <br /> generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer <br /> widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  <br /> among his fans  substring";

Ben Nadel   // explain here user find br tag it fine to go next line 
reviews the  // why not it display 30 characters ?
various approaches to Sachin
Ramesh Tendulkar is a former
                             //why boac space display
Indian cricketer widely
acknowledged as the greatest
batsman of the modern 
generation, popularly holds
the title among his fans
Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a
former Indian cricketer 
widely acknowledged as the
greatest batsman of the modern
generation, popularly holds
the title among his
fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is
a former Indian cricketer
widely acknowledged as the
greatest batsman of the modern
generation, popularly holds
the title                    //why 30 character not display ?
among his
fans substring
```

I want need some logic .if there is br tag in string it come to new line and again  it display 30 character (whole words) ?
can we do this ?
http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/11/

```
for(var index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
{
    var currentWord = words[index];
    var currentLength = tenLengthString.length;    
    if(((currentLength + currentWord.length + ((currentLength > 0) ? 1: 0))) > 30)
    {        
        html+='<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';
        console.log(tenLengthString);        
        tenLengthString = currentWord;        
    } else {
        if(currentLength > 0)
            tenLengthString += " ";    
        tenLengthString += currentWord;
    }    
    if(index == words.length - 1){
      console.log(tenLengthString);
       html+='<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';

    }        
}
$("#test").html(html)
```

Comment: can you please use fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep the breaks, you should first split the string on those. Then use your existing code for each block.

```
function cleanBreak(str){
    return str
            .replace(/<br >/g, "<br>")
            .replace(/<br \/>/g, "<br>")
            .replace(/<br\/>/g, "<br>");
}

var str = "Ben Nadel <br /> reviews the various approaches to Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former <br /> Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern <br /> generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer <br /> widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  <br /> among his fans  substring";
var phrases = cleanBreak(str).split("<br>");
var html=[];
for(var pIndex = 0; pIndex < phrases.length; pIndex++){
    html.push("<div class='phrase'>");
    var words = phrases[pIndex].split(" ");
    var tenLengthString = "";
    for(var index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
    {
        var currentWord = words[index];
        var currentLength = tenLengthString.length;    
        if(((currentLength + currentWord.length + ((currentLength > 0) ? 1: 0))) > 30)
        {        
            html.push('<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>');
            console.log(tenLengthString);        
            tenLengthString = currentWord;        
        } else {
            if(currentLength > 0)
                tenLengthString += " ";    
            tenLengthString += currentWord;
        }    
        if(index == words.length - 1){
          console.log(tenLengthString);
           html.push('<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>');

        }        
    }
    html.push("</div>");
}
$("#test").html(html.join(''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9TZhE/
(I added some formatting to see what's going on)

Comment: i think you not understand the question ..sorry i will tell you again

Comment: you out put is this Ben Nadel
Ben Nadel reviews the
various approaches to Sachin
Ramesh Tendulkar is a former
Ramesh Tendulkar is a former
Indian cricketer widely
acknowledged as the greatest

Comment: Ben Nadel is right .there is no need to right Ben Nadel  ?second line should be reviews the various

Comment: I have updated it. The `tenLengthString` had to be scoped inside the phrase loop.

Comment: I think a RegExp such as `/<br\s*\/?>/` may be a bit more robust.

Comment: Yes, a RegExp would be better. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yourString.indexOf('<br />')` which will return index of the first position of `<br />` or -1 if there is no `<br />` found.

Answer (score 0):

Different thought. http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/13/

```
html = html.replace(/<br >/g, "").replace(/<br \/>/g, "")      .replace(/<br\/>/g, "");
$("#test").html(html)
```